# Wildcard (*) support in a bash script to Copy/Remove files/folders

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script which works fine, except that it does not accept wildcard (*). Any idea how I can support it ?

```
#!/bin/bash

currentPath="testCurrent/"
newPath="testNew/"
logFile=test.txt
configFile=test.csv

copy_files() {
  local relativePath="$1"
  local overwrite="$2"

  local source="${newPath%/}/${relativePath}"
  local destination="${currentPath%/}/${relativePath}"

  log_message "Copying: $source -> $destination (overwrite=$overwrite)"

  destination="${destination%/}"
  destination="${destination%/*}"

  mkdir -p "$destination"

  if [ "$overwrite" = true ]; then
    log_message "Copying (overwrite) $source to $destination"
    cp -r "$source" "$destination" 2>&1 | tee -a "$logFile"
  else
    log_message "Copying $source to $destination"
    cp -rn "$source" "$destination" 2>&1 | tee -a "$logFile"
  fi
}

remove_files() {
  local relativePath="$1"

  if [ -n "$relativePath" ]; then
    local destination="${currentPath%/}/${relativePath}"
    log_message "Removing $destination"
    rm -r "$destination" 2>&1 | tee -a "$logFile"
  fi
}

log_message() {
  local message="$1"
  echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - $message" | tee -a "$logFile"
}

cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
log_message "Working folder: $(pwd)"

log_message "Start looping through $configFile"
while IFS=, read -r operation relativePath overwrite || [ -n "$operation" ]; do
  case "$operation" in
  "Copy") copy_files "$relativePath" "$overwrite" ;;
  "Remove") remove_files "$relativePath" ;;
  esac
done <"$configFile"
```

And the csv:

```
Copy,testCopy DirNoSlashNoOverwrite,false
Copy,testCopy DirNoSlashOverwrite,true
Copy,testCopy DirSlashNoOverwrite/,false
Copy,testCopy DirSlashOverwrite/,true
Copy,testCopy DirSlashStarNoOverwrite/*,false
Copy,testCopy DirSlashStarOverwrite/*,true
Copy,testCopy FileNoOverwrite/existing.txt,false
Copy,testCopy FileNoOverwrite/new.txt,false
Copy,testCopy FileOverwrite/existing.txt,true
Copy,testCopy FileOverwrite/new.txt,true
Remove,testRemove DirNoSlash
Remove,testRemove DirSlash/
Remove,testRemove DirSlashStar/*
Remove,testRemove File/existing.txt
```

The 3 lines in csv with /* do not work. Ex:
cp: cannot stat 'testNew/testCopy DirSlashStarNoOverwrite/*': No such file or directory

`testNew/testCopy DirSlashStarNoOverwrite/` folder contains files and folders in reality, but it looks like the * is seen as a standard char and not expanded.

I know it is due to paths being enclosed in quotes but if I remove, spaces are no more handled. I have tried many combinations but cannot find something that works with * and spaces.

Comment: Put the wildcard expansion in an array. However, arrays are not first-class and can't be passed as function arguments, you'll need to use global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you hit the nail on the head in your closing comments - you can't easily disable the special meaning of whitespace without also disabling the special meaning of the glob.

It's a bit cumbersome, but one alternative is to use a tool that doesn't rely on bash expanding the glob as a wrapper to the command you're trying to run. Using `find` for example:

```
depth="${destination//[^\/]}" # prevent find from navigating into subdirectories
find -maxdepth "${#depth}" -path "$destination" -exec rm -r {} + 2>&1 | tee -a "$logFile"
```

For more complex inputs or commands, it would make sense to delegate to something with easier syntax like `python` or `perl`.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried find but either it finds nothing or it copies to some upper level. And, for my usage, I need the less dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by disabling [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) while allowing [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (aka "globbing").  Do this by setting [IFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS) to the empty (aka "null") string and not quoting the expansion for which globbing is required.

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean short program (written in our house style for my convenience) demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

function copy_files
{
    local -r files_pat=$1
    local -r destdir=$2

    # Set IFS to empty to stop work splitting in unquoted expansions
    local IFS=''

    # shellcheck disable=SC2086 # (Need globbing so cannot quote $files_pat)
    cp -v -- $files_pat "$destdir"
}

copy_files 'dir a/*.txt' 'dir b'
```

- `local IFS=''` sets `IFS` to the empty string to prevent word splitting in expansions, but localizes the change to the `copy_files` function so other parts of the program don't break due to `IFS` having an unusual value.
- `# shellcheck disable=SC2086 ...` silences a [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warning about an unquoted expansion.
- In `cp -v -- $files_pat "$destdir"`, `$files_pat` is subject to globbing (because it is not quoted) but not word splitting (because `IFS` is empty).  `"$destdir"` is subject to neither word splitting nor globbing because it is quoted.
- `copy_files 'dir a/*.txt' 'dir b'` will copy all files with a `.txt` suffix in a subdirectory called `dir a` of the current directory to a subdirectory called `dir b`.

A limitation of this technique is that it won't work for copying from paths that contain globbing metacharacters (`*`, `?`, ...).  For instance, you've got a problem in the example above if the source directory is called `dir*a` instead of `dir a`.